# VB.NET Text To Speech and Multiple Languages

Tags: vb.net

I would like to switch between languages at runtime using the microsoft TTS synthesizer (or whatever will work) in a vb.net application on an English version of Windows. In a nutshell, what I would like to do is this:

```
Dim tts As New SpeechSynthesizer
If Language.IsEnglish Then
      tts.SpeakAsync("Yes") ' English translation provided
ElseIf Language.IsFrenchCanadian Then
      tts.SpeakAsync("We") ' French translation will be provided
End If
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: No, SpeechSynthesizer was not designed to translate, only to speak.  You'll have to say "Nous" with a French voice selected.

Comment: Understood on the translator, I will have the french translation to pass to speakasync. Are you saying that I will just need a french voice and it will take care of the rest (accent and correct pronunciation etc.)?

Comment: Erm, there is no "rest".  Select the voice and SpeakAsync().  You'll have to purchase the voice.

Comment: Any suggestion on where to purchase the voice?

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel/languages. Just download the needed language pack. Once downloaded go to start button and settings gear icon. Time and language/region and language/ all language packs you have downloaded are there. click on one you want and click options. under speech, click download. This is for win10.